# How can I convert all values in a column like '€226.5M' or '€100.1K' (type object) to 226.5 or 0.1001 (type float) while working with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have this DataFrame and I know I should use the replace method, but I don't in which way.
I want all values in the column to be floats in million euros, so I would erase the '€', also the 'M' and if a value has a 'K' instead of an 'M', erase the K and make the number 1000 times smaller.
Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqbvU.png

Comment: "*I have this DataFrame*" -> but we don't, can you share a sample (as **text**)? and also provide the expected output?

Comment: I've just put a link of the picture. The expected output would be the df['Release Column'] to have all values converted (i.e. €196.4M to 196.4 or €143K to 0.143).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a custom function to convert string values to numeric:

```
mappings = {'M': 1, 'K': 0.001}

def to_numeric(sr):
    df = sr.str.extract('([^€KM]+)([KM]?)')
    return df[0].astype(float) * df[1].map(mappings).astype(float)

# Convert your columns
df['Value'] = to_numeric(df['Value'])
df['Wage'] = to_numeric(df['Wage'])
df['Release Clause'] = to_numeric(df['Release Clause'])
```

Comment: @Hernan. I posted a new solution. I tried on the `fifa19` dataset and all values are converted to numeric according your requirements.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you